# Swagger - how to define a multi-dimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, swagger

I could not find any examples of this. Maybe because of the lack of my Swagger knowledge or maybe there are no similiar examples.

Is possible to write a swagger definition where an exposed type is a multidimentional array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since swagger uses [Json Schema](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/) to model the types being exposed over your API, you really need to know how to model a multidimensional (Nd) array in Json Schema.

The answer is: there is no built in support for Nd arrays in Json Schema.

However, json schema does support [arrays](https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/arrays/), and there's nothing preventing the items in an array from being arrays themselves. So you can define Nd arrays by just using an arrays of arrays.

```
"2dArrayOfInt": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "integer" // This will be a 2d array of numbers
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Not nice, but then neither are Nd arrays.

Comment: I realy appreciate that you've answered me tom redfern. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem @0xhiryuu. That is the largest number of instances of the word "array" in a single answer I have ever written.